# Large CSV with Apache Camel + Aggregator

Tags: csv, apache-camel

Generate big files with Apache Camel with Aggregator with better performance as this post: [Large Files with Apache Camel](http://www.catify.com/2012/07/09/parsing-large-files-with-apache-camel/)

My body has 33352 rows.. and using `completionSize="1000"` and `completionTimeout="2500"` the final file missed the last 352 rows

```xml
<camel:split streaming="true">
  <camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple>
  <camel:marshal>
    <camel:csv quote='"' quoteDisabled="false" headerDisabled="true" />
  </camel:marshal>
  <camel:aggregate strategyRef="setfepCsvStringBodyAggregator" completionSize="1000" completionTimeout="2500">
    <camel:correlationExpression>
      <constant>true</constant>
    </camel:correlationExpression>
    <to uri="file:{{setfep_dir_inprogress}}/?fileName={{setfep_filename_clientes}}.txt&amp;fileExist=Append" />
  </camel:aggregate>
</camel:split>
```

Final file has 33000 rows missing 352.

```
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
```

if I use `completionSize="1000"` and `completionInterval="2500"` my final file has 33155 hows missing 197 rows.

```
[Camel thread #0 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=interval rows=566
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[Camel thread #0 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=interval rows=43
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[Camel thread #0 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=interval rows=401
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[Camel thread #0 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=interval rows=768
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[Camel thread #0 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=interval rows=377
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
[main] [INFO ]  CamelLogger.log - Complete by=size rows=1000
```

How to fix this?

`Apache Camel 2.19.0`

Answer (score 0):

**gotcha!**

I running as unit test... the context ends before complete `completionInterval` or `completionTimeout`

when I put a delay in my route I could see the total 33352 rows wrote.

```xml
<camel:delay>
  <constant>5000</constant>
</camel:delay>
```

But in production isn't necessary, the context continue alive or we can use the option `forceCompletionOnStop`:

```xml
<camel:aggregate strategyRef="setfepCsvStringBodyAggregator" forceCompletionOnStop="true" completionSize="1000" completionInterval="4000">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregator needs to know when it's done aggregating and can release the message it's currently aggregating.  You actually have 2 criteria.  You have the size you want to batch, but since you have less than 1_000 in your last batch, it keeps waiting.  But you have a signal you are currently ignoring.  If you add a Completion Predicate to look for when the last message is received (Exchange property `SPLIT_COMPLETE` is present and true) then the aggregator will release its last batch.

In the Java DSL this would be:
`.completionPredicate(exchangeProperty(SPLIT_COMPLETE).isEqualTo(TRUE))`